# How does this python palindrome function work?

Tags: python, palindrome

can someone explain this function to me?

```py
#from the geeksforgeeks website

  def isPalimdrome(str): 
    for i in range(0, int(len(str)/2)):
        if str[i] != str[len(str)-i-1]:
            return False
    return True
```

I dont understand the for loop and the if statement.

A - why is the range from 0 to length of the string divided by 2?
B - what does "str[len(str)-i-1" do?

//sorry, ik I ask stupid questions

Comment: I've been hating geeksforgeeks anyways, but oh this code is horrible in several ways. The question is not stupid, the code is. Learn with something better.

Comment: Can you show me a better one, please?

Comment: Just `return s == s[::-1]` would suffice, when `s` is the argument of the function. Although it _might_ (?) be slightly less efficient, but it gains huge readability. Never use `str` as a custom name.

Comment: The point of `len(s) / 2` is that you only need to check half the letters.

Comment: It is comparing the 1st letter to the last and moving inwards.  It only needs to cover half the length of the word since it is looking at the edges and will converge at the middle.

Comment: Oh thanks. Ive used the [::-1], but someone told me its slow, so i thought i should look for another way

Comment: IMHO, unless you are checking strings of several GBs, `[::-1]` is fine. Of course people may have different opinions.

Comment: yoda: Who told you using `[::-1]` is slow? You should distrust claims on those coding-grind sites.

Comment: Also, I've just tested with a 100M file. `[::-1]` took 0.22 seconds, and the geeksforgeeks' `isPalindrome` took 8.88 seconds.

Comment: Smci: it was someone on discord

Answer (score 3):

To determine if a string is a palindrome, we can split the string in half and compare each letter of each half.

Consider the example

```
string ABCCBA
```

the range in the for loop sets this up by only iterating over the first n/2 characters. int(n/2) is used to force an integer (question A)

```
ex_str = 'ABCCBA'

for s in range(int(len(ex_str)/2)):
    print(ex_str[s])
A
B
C
```

we now have to look at the letters in the other half, CBA, in reverse order

adding an index to our example to visualize this

```
string ABCCBA
index  012345
```

to determine if string is a palindrome, we can compare indices 0 to 5, 1 to 4, and 2 to 3

`len(str)-i-1` gives us the correct index of the other half for each i (question B)

example:

```
ex_str = 'ABCCBA'

for s in range(int(len(ex_str)/2)):
    print(f'compare index {s} to index {len(ex_str)-s-1}')
    print(f"{ex_str[s]} to {ex_str[len(ex_str) - s - 1]}")
compare index 0 to index 5
A to A
compare index 1 to index 4
B to B
compare index 2 to index 3
C to C
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
for i in range(0, int(len(str)/2)):
```

Iterate through(go one by one from) 0(because in string first letter's index is 0) to half length of the string.

Why to only half length?

Because in a palindrome you need to compare only half length of string to the other half.

e.g., RADAR. 0=R, 1=A, 2=D, 3=A, 4=R. Number of letters = 5.

`int(len(str)/2)` will evaluate to 2. So first two letters will be compared with last two letters and middle one is common so will not be compared.

```py
if str[i] != str[len(str)-i-1]:
```

Now, length of string is 5 but index of letters in string goes from 0 to 4, which is why `len(str)-1` (5-1 = 4, i.e., last letter R).

`len(str)-1-i` Since i is a loop variable, it will be incremented by 1 every time for loop runs. In first run i is 0, in second 1....

The for loop will run two times.

`str[i] != str[len(str)-1-i]` will be evaluated as-

1. 0 != 4 i.e. R != R     FALSE
2. 1 != 3 i.e. A != A     FALSE

This code is not very readable and can be simplified as pointed out by others. This also reflects why code readability is important.

Answer (score 1):

###### 1. why is the range from 0 to length of the string divided by 2?

That's because we don't need to iterate all the way through the string but just halfway through it.

###### 2. what does "str[len(str)-i-1]" do?

It returns the `i`th element from the end ie for a string `"noon"` when `i` is `0` it will get str[3] ie `n`

Comment: Yea i know, it isnt my code. Thank you so much

Comment: @KellyBundy You're right my bad, Thank-you.

Answer (score -1):

Easiest way to check palindrome is this

```
def isPalimdrome(s):
    return s == s[::-1]
```

Reading the string from the beginning is same as reading it reverse.

Comment: You're completely ignoring the question. This is not an answer.